# Cannot apply border to iframe from inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I'm inside an iFrame. I control the inner/outer/parent/child contents and it's all within the same domain. There are no security exceptions.

If I run this in Chrome console, the border is applied exactly like I want:

```
$("[name='PPDGFrame']").css("border", "2px solid #334930");
```

Yet when I do the same exact thing programmatically, it never works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("[name='PPDGFrame'], window.parent.document").css("border", "2px solid #334930");
});
```

Or even this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
       $("[name='PPDGFrame'], window.parent.document").css("border", "2px solid #334930");
   }, 3000);
});
```

When executed in the code, no errors exist, and in Console I clearly get a handle to the object. Still no border.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify `window.parent.document` as the [`context` for the `selector`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) to search within, it should be passed as a separate argument after the string.

```
$("[name='PPDGFrame']", window.parent.document)
//                   ^^
```

Currently, being in the selector, the `,` is understood as a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and `window.parent.document` as an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) with [class selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) searching for:

```
<window class="parent document">
```

It's a valid selector, which is why you don't receive any errors. It just isn't matching anything either as you probably don't have such an element in your document.